# Simple command line JSON tool equivalent of nbstripout for Zeppelin notebooks

Tags: json, bash, jq, apache-zeppelin

**Some background**

Versioning notebooks can become very inefficient if the output is expected to vary a lot. I solved this problem with my Jupyter notebooks using [`nbstripout`](https://github.com/kynan/nbstripout), but so far I've found no alternative for Zeppelin notebooks.

Because `nbstripout` uses `nbformat` to parse `ipynb` files, it's not an easy patch to make it support Zeppelin. On the other hand, the goal is not that complex: simply empty out all the `"msg": "..."`.

**Goal**

Given a JSON file, empty out all `'paragraphs.result.msg'` fields.

**Sample** (schema):

```
{"paragraps": [{"result": {"msg": "Very long output..."}}]}
```

Comment: I am working on a python script using json parsing, but if someone can solve this faster using some command line utility I'll prefer it instead. Otherwise I'll answer with my own script.

Comment: I didn't know `jq`, that's nice. `.paragraphs[].result.msg = ""` seems to do the trick. Now I just need to apply it everywhere with some shell magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Git Filter

The best solution (thanks to @steven-penny) is to run this:

`git config filter.znbstripout.clean "jq '.paragraphs[].result.msg = \"\"'"`

which will setup a filter called `znbstripout` that invokes the `jq` tool. Then, in your `.gitattributes` file you can just put:

`*.json filter=znbstripout`

### Python Script (usable with Git Hooks)

The following can be used as a git hook:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from glob import glob
import json

files = glob('**/note.json', recursive=True)
for file in files:
    with open(file, 'r') as fp:
        nb = json.load(fp)
    for p in nb['paragraphs']:
        if 'result' in p:
            p['result']['msg'] = ""
    with open(file, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(nb, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=2)
```

Answer (score 2):

In (1) and (2) below, I'll assume that the incoming JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "paragraphs": [
    {
      "result": {
        "msg": "msg1"
      }
    },
    {
      "result": {
        "msg": "msg2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### 1. To set the .result.msg values to ""

```
.paragraphs[].result.msg = ""
```

#### 2. To remove the .result.msg fields altogether:

```
del(.paragraphs[].result.msg)
```

#### 3. To remove "msg" fields in all objects, wherever they occur:

```
walk(if type == "object" then del(.msg) else . end)
```

(If your jq does not have `walk`, google: jq faq walk)

#### 4. To remove "msg" fields wherever they occur in a .result object in a  .paragraphs array:

```
 walk(if type == "object" and (.paragraphs|type) == "array"
      then del(.paragraphs[].result?.msg?) else . end)
```

Answer (score 1):

JQ can do this:

```
jq .paragraphs[].result.msg file
```

http://stedolan.github.io/jq

Comment: I guess it should be `.paragraphs[].result.msg = ""`, since I want a replacement. But thats much nicer, this way I can directly put the command in a git filter.